# Infowindows Displayed on the Same Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

```
for (var i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locs[i][0], locs[i][1])
                    , map: map
                    , title: "Hello World!"
                    , icon: iconImage
                    , clickable: true
                });

                marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    marker.info.open(map, marker);
                });
            }
```

All markers are displayed well on the map, but the problem is when I click to see info window - info window is always displayed on the same marker. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your marker variable is not persisting outside the scope of your foreach loop, I'd think that the maps api is not keeping track of them properly. It's good practice when working with markers to save the active ones in an array, that way you can dispose of them later (or otherwise manage them). Try something like this:

```
var markers = Array(); //make sure this is scoped properly

for (var i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locs[i][0], locs[i][1])
        , map: map
        , title: "Hello World!"
        , icon: iconImage
        , clickable: true
    });

    var index = markers.push(marker) -1;

    markers[index].info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[index], 'click', function () {
        marker.info.open(map, marker);
    });        
}
```